# Downgrade Windows 8.1 Pro with Media Center to Windows 8.1 Pro

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-media-center, downgrade

I built my own computer, and bought a copy of Windows 8 Pro about a year ago. Entered my product key and everything during setup, went smoothly. When Windows 8.1 came out I upgraded through the Windows Store app. I also wanted to try out Windows Media Center so, I'll be honest here, I looked up a product key for it (didn't buy) and it somehow worked, so I had Windows 8.1 Pro with Media Center. I just wanted to try it out, not keep it.

Unfortunately, the key was blocked, so Windows is now nagging me to activate every 3 hours or so. I want to return to my legit product key to stop this and return to Windows 8.1 Pro, but when I enter the key I bought (remember, it's a Windows 8 key, not 8.1), it says that the key can't be used to activate this edition of Windows. What should I do? I want to avoid clean re-installing Windows 8 if possible.

Comment: Try [this](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6673-add-features-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: @Chipperyman I can't open the Anytime Upgrade utility, probably because I can't upgrade. None of the methods work for opening it, so that's useless.

Comment: What about [this](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/16077-media-center-remove-go-back-windows-8-pro.html)?

Comment: @Chipperyman I have an OEM key and I need to download an ISO of Windows 8 Pro, but they're saying it won't work with an OEM key.

Comment: There is no way to downgrade once you upgrade.  Who says it won't work provide a link because the OEM license should activate.  Just purchase the key....

Comment: @Ramhound [this link](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/18309-windows-8-windows-8-1-iso-download-create.html) says I can't get a Windows 8 download with an OEM key. I'd hate to purchase another key when I already have one.

Comment: You can't get a Windows 8 .ISO with anything other then a Windows 8.1 retail license or a Windows 8.0 Upgrade license.  I assumed you had an installation disk. Your question spoke nothing of not having an installation disk.

Comment: I do have an installation disk. Just no CD drive. I guess I should go and get one. The CD drive I used when I was installing isn't working anymore.

Comment: Why don't you just [disable](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15530/uninstall-disable-or-remove-windows-7-media-center/) it? That's what I did.

Comment: Because that won't help with the activation problem. I want to go back to Windows 8.1 Pro because it was activated and working at that time. The key I used for Media Center wasn't valid, so Windows is now nagging me every few hours to activate it.